# What are Gibdo Guts useful for?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

Gibdo Guts are a rare drop from Gibdos (10%) and Moth Gibdos (20%), but they are much less useful than Gibdo Bones, which are much more common. They have a sale value of 2, which is one ruppee less than that of the Gibdo Bone. They have a fuse attack power of one, which is equivalent to that of a common rock or apple. Although they add slightly more duration than basic ingredients, they are easily outdone by any other monster gut, and their rarity makes them ill-suited to this purpose. The one situation where they are required is the five needed to upgrade the sand boots, and this seems like it easily could have been swapped for some other desert item. Is upgrading the sand boots the only use for Gibdo Guts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you said, they are only needed to upgrade Sand Boots:

[image]

<sup>(taken from [Game8](https://game8.co/games/Zelda-Tears-of-the-Kingdom/archives/412362#hl_2))</sup>

And even as an ingredient they are outclassed by other monster guts (added time of 1:20min instead of 2:40min), but...

Items like **Golden Apple**, **Star Fragment**, each **Dragon part** (except the Spikes), and also **Gibdo Guts** give you a guaranteed *critical cooking* with a boosted effect if you use them for your recipe.

Other monster guts (and also Sugar Cane) give an increased critical chance of 30%, against the 10% base. This is also explained by [Austin John Plays](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ho3fZyokkg8).

---

For more information there's also a [useful datasheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fBvQ17WHP3ASgtO8ode_rf1g4DfEHErMrHwwLppNTJM/edit#gid=1158062068&range=A1) about every ingredient.